# Redis Mass Insertion with newlines in values

Tags: redis, insert, newline

I am trying to generate a file for mass insertion in shape:

```
SET Key0 Value0
SET Key1 Value1
...
SET KeyN ValueN
```

In my case, I have newlines in values. How to write values in this case since `\n` means new command. Can I use quotation mark to wrap a value with a newline character?

Comment: Yes, you can. Why don't try it instead of posting a question? If you fail, come back with the details :)

Comment: I wrap my values like this `SET key "value with \n in between"` but I still get `ERR unknown command`. It looks like that Redis still interpret newlines inside values as a start of the new command. So how can I wrap values with newlines inside that will not raise this error.

Answer (score 3):

Redis doesn't care about what you store as string values. What may be getting in your way is the client/programming language that you're using.

For example, the below is the output of using the `redis-cli` tool that ships with Redis:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> SET foo "1st\n2nd"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> GET foo
"1st\n2nd"
127.0.0.1:6379> QUIT
$ redis-cli --raw
127.0.0.1:6379> GET foo
1st
2nd
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. My problem was that I did not escape newlines when writing insertion file in Python. Newlines need to be written as a string "\n" inside value and not as a real newline.

Comment: Ah - that's why it's always good to attach the code to the question :)